# Automating this function with a loop taking multiple inputs - Python 3.7

Tags: python, loops, input

I have written a function that predicts stock data using ESM. It takes two inputs, one being a column name, and the other being the training ratio. Now, I have set it up to take these as user inputs, and so I have to manually type them in everytime I run  it. There are 4 columns, and each column (stock) needs to be run at training ratios of 0.6, 0.7, 0.8 and 0.9. So, I will need a loop that starts off by taking the first column, then takes the 4 ratios for this one by one and then moves to the next column. Any help with this will be appreciated.

I tried googling it, but could not find anything specific. Trust me guys, I tried. Sorry, Im an absolute noob at this. Please see below part of the code that's relevant to the problem.

```py
def esm():
    data  = input('Please Enter Stock Name: ')
    ratio = float(input('Please enter split: '))

    X = series[data].values
    size = int(len(X) * ratio)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it what you want?
You can make your esm function can take two parameters and you can reuse this function in loop.

```
def esm(data, ratio):
    X = series[data].values
    size = int(len(X) * ratio)


for data in ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]:
    for ratio in [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]:
        esm(data, ratio)
        # do something
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Terry! I will give it a go!

Comment: That did it! Appreciate it!

Comment: Happy that helped!